# Using IF to return cell contents in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

---

Edit for clarity:

The end result that I'm looking for will pass the name picked from the dropdown list in B1 into formulas below to check if each student has completed the training modules listed. The two sheets I'm looking at (for now) are 'Data' and 'Quick Reference' the rest are just placeholders.

---

I've looked and not found an answer so apologies if this has been asked before!

I'm trying to write a formula that will check form results and if it finds a match, return the contents from another column in that row.

The logical IF function works fine with hard coded entries, but not with cell contents.

So if I'm looking for "Deckhand USS Minnow I" I want to show the contents of Column H. Look on the Data and Quick Reference (Training Progress) tabs to see what I'm talking about.

This works:

```
=IF(((VLOOKUP($B1,Data!C2:J20,4)="Build Coconut Phone I")),"Yes", "No")
```

This doesn't:

```
=IF(((VLOOKUP($B1,Data!C2:J20,4)="Deckhand USS Minnow IV")),Data!H2:H20)
```

[Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15q_KVfOWaHxcftTCAA0tYLBFTtNSpeRkc-Z_I08Od_U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: See [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Use `QUERY()` instead of `IF(Vlookup(),)`

```
=QUERY(Data!C1:J20,"Select H where F = 'Deckhand USS Minnow IV'",1)
```

## Explanation

While could be possible to use an array formula using `IF` and `VLOOKUP`,  `QUERY()` does the work in a direct and simple way.

The formula in the short answer will include the column heading. If you don't want it use

```
=QUERY(Data!C2:J20,"Select H where F = 'Deckhand USS Minnow IV'",0)
```

## References

- [QUERY - Google Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Comment: I tried it and got "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in E7"....Edit... it seems to be populating E7 if I delete the formula that was in that cell.

Comment: @Rachel: The image is self-explanatory. The "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in E7". In your spreadsheet there are two rows with 'Deckhand USS Minnow IV' so, the result is an array of 2x1 (two rows, one column).

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer here. I need the Training Progress box to only pull results that match the name from the dropdown in B1.

Comment: @Rachel: Please update your question to make it clear where do you want to display the result of the formula.

Comment: I put some comments in the sheet that I've shared to help but the answer is that cell E6 should return "Yes."  if the dropdown at the top is "Maryanne"